# Laravel 8 Atomic Locks with MySQL driver perform different actions depending on web browser

Tags: php, laravel, google-chrome, firefox, caching

guys!
I have a simple route: *example.com/dev* that call a controller with Atomic Lock code.
While first request executing this code, the second request should wait a time if lock exists, but it working depending on web browser.

Code in controller:

```
$a = [];

$time = time();
$lock = Cache::lock('foo', 60);

try 
{
    $lock->block(20);
    
    $a['start'] = time() - $time;
    sleep(5);
    $a['end'] = time() - $time;
} 
catch (LockTimeoutException $e) 
{
    $a['nothing'] = true;
} 
finally 
{
    optional($lock)->release();
}

print_r($a);
```

Then I use two browsers Chrome and Firefox to execute this code.

***1-st test***: I call Chrome, then immediately Firefox.

Chrome result: `Array ( [start] => 0 [end] => 5 )`
Firefox result: `Array ( [start] => 5 [end] => 10 )`

*All as expected!*

***2-nd test***: Firefox first tab, then Firefox second tab

Firefox first tab result: `Array ( [start] => 0 [end] => 5 )`
Firefox second tab result: `Array ( [start] => 5 [end] => 10 )`

*Also as expected!*

***3-rd test***: Chrome first tab, then Chrome second tab

Chrome first tab result: `Array ( [start] => 0 [end] => 5 )`
Chrome second tab result: `Array ( [start] => 0 [end] => 5 )`

*There are no locking!*
Also no locking on Edge browser. My dev instance: Ubuntu 20.04 / PHP 7.4 / MariaDB 10.4.10

Could someone explain whats going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Your code is not browser dependent. It's probably how the browser is handling the response of the server. Check your Dev pane and look in the network tab to see if Chrome is using its internal cache. That could explain that it's showing the same response.

Comment: Oh, my! I changed my requests URLs in Chrome for /dev?x=111 and /dev?x=222 and receive what I expected. I did not know about this browsers feature! THANK YOU!